# Visual Studio 2013 crash on first launch

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I installed VS2015 then I uninstalled it and re-intalled vs2013. I have tried all solutions:

1. Opened the program in safe mode
2. Reset settings
3. Re-installed the program

Please assist, I need to work in VS2013.

[image: This the image I have when the progarm starts up]

Comment: What is the debug report?

Comment: The program '[2500] devenv.exe: Native' has exited with code -2146232797 (0x80131623).

Answer (score 0):

As You have told that you have tried running the VS2013 in safemode and even have tried reinstalling so:
GoTo **

> Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Windows Features

**
disabled .NET 3.5

You can still Try some devenv switches in command prompt:

a. Run `devenv /Resetsettings` to eliminate the cause of corrupted settings.

b. Run `devenv /ResetSkipPkgs` in Command Prompt.

c. Run `devenv /Safemode` to see if you can apply it correctly. This can eliminate the possibility that third party Add-ins or packages are causing problems.

I think disabling NET 3.5 will work.

Comment: I have disabled the the features. Same problem

Comment: please see this , this might help: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c3f11b48-813b-46e6-b591-76527fed5f37/visual-studio-2013-has-stopped-working-in-windows-81?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Comment: I have tried all the options and they all dont seem to be working